In GCP Kubernetes does having a pod finalizer stop SIGKILL signals going to your application until the finalizer is removed?
In GCP Kubernetes does having a pod finalizer stop SIGKILL signals going to your application/OS until the finalizer is removed?
I ask this because I have an application where a user's request may run for up to 3 hours and I don't want to terminate the pod and applications until it's complete.


...does having a pod finalizer stop SIGKILL signals going to your application/OS until the finalizer is removed?

No. Finalizer is used by controller to perform clean-up task. This happens after SIGKILL was sent to terminate container.

...I have an application where a user's request may run for up to 3 hours and I don't want to terminate the pod and applications until it's complete

You can set terminiationGracePeriodSeconds to 10800 (3 x 3600s) to ensure your pod has ample time to complete.

terminiationGracePeriodSeconds has a hard limit of 600 seconds. Unless you know of a way of overriding this?
"Warning: autopilot-default-resources-mutator:The max supported TerminationGracePeriodSeconds is 600 seconds. Defaulting down from configured 10800 seconds to 600 seconds."

Nope, there isn't a hard limit. Your cluster has some kind of auto scaler running.
